# "Io non ci sono": che cosa significa in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Gioco del matto soto la croce* (o *I crozadór*) di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> CAPO INCHIOVATORI    
>   D'accordo. Forza, allargatevi voi 
>   due che gli mettiamo le ali a questo angiolotto [cosí] che possa volare come Icaro nel cielo. 
>   (*Pausa*). Tiriamo insieme... Insieme, ho detto!... Me lo rovesciate! Piano che deve restare in mezzo della sella il cavaliere... Un 
>   po' di piú verso me... bene, sono sul segno... proprio nel buco. (*Indica il foro di abbrivio già approntato nella 
>   tavola*). 
>   SECONDO INCHIOVATORE    
>   **Io non ci sono**, hai fatto i 
>   buchi troppo distanti... tira tu... forza! Hai mangiato il formaggio a mezzogiorno? Forza!

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "io non ci sono" in questo passaggio. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Probabilmente equivale a  "Io non sono pronto". Lavorando in squadra si dice "Ci sei?" al compagno proprio per chiedere se è pronto ad eseguire un'azione che richiede un coordinamento.

Comment: Puoi metterlo come risposta, @RiccardoDeContardi?

Answer (score 3):

Nel contesto da te citato l'espressione **io non ci sono** indica che il secondo inchiodatore si accorge che l'oggetto che stanno spostando non è nella posizione giusta.

Infatti specifica che ha fatto i buchi troppo distanti e mentre da una parte combacia con il foro dall'altra non è perfettamente in posizione, da qui la richiesta di tirare un poco nella direzione opposta.

Da Treccani per [essere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/essere1/):

> b. Contiene spesso l’idea del moto: *e. in via, in cammino, in viaggio*
>   (anche fig.: *e. in via di guarigione*); e per indicare il punto a cui
>   si è arrivati nel progredire di un fatto, di un’attività, in una serie
>   d’azioni: *e. al principio, alla fine, e. avanti, indietro, a buon
>   punto; e. alla minestra, alla frutta; l’acqua è a bollore*. Usato
>   assol., esserci, aver raggiunto lo scopo, riuscire in qualche cosa:
>   *coraggio, che ci sei*;

Answer (score 3):

Equivale a *"Io non sono pronto"*. Lavorando in squadra si dice "Ci sei?" al compagno proprio per chiedere se è pronto ad eseguire un'azione che richiede un coordinamento.